# Как передать значения переменной из useState не по ссылке?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Впервые столкнулся с проблемой передачи по значению/ссылке в JS. Использую хук useState. И обнаружил что переменные, созданные с помощью такого хука, передаются в другие по ссылке. Да не просто по ссылке, а их ещё и дополнять можно.

```
const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
...
setTime(Date.now()); // времени между этими операциями достаточно
...
let currentTime = time + 1; // да, const тоже пробовал
setTime(0)                  // эта строчка уже в результате отчаяных эксперементов появилась
console.log(
  `cur time: ${currentTime}`,
  `   time: ${time}`,
  "\n\n"
);
```

А потом в консоль мне выдают:

```
cur time: 0
    time: 1     // вот тут я ожидаю что-то вроде 1602005420
```

Вопрос: как я могу отдать в currentTime текущее значение и дальше работать с time, не меняя значени currentTime?

P.S. Что я уже пробовал:

- `let time` вместо `[time, setTime]` - работает, но разве нет способов с хуками?
- const time - результат такой же
- ещё одна промежуточная переменная `const _time = currentTime` - меняются обе без моего вмешательства

P.P.S. Я знаю, что объекты в JS передаются по ссылке, но, простите, я вывожу в консоль тип данных time и получаю Number.

Comment: `объекты в JS передаются по ссылке` - это неверно, всё в js передаётся по значению, включая указатели на объекты

Comment: Можете на примере [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-5j6cmm?file=index.tsx) показать, что у вас не получается?

Comment: useState — фича для компонентов-функций, для ререндера функция [всегда вызывается заново](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-5j6cmm?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.tsx). Если currentTime в области видимости функции, она уничтожается и создаётся новая.

Comment: @vp_arth Спасибо, про области видимости я не подумал. Оформите, пожалуйста, ответ, чтоб я отметил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useState — фича для компонентов-функций, для ререндера функция всегда вызывается заново.

Предположу, что у вас `let currentState` определён внутри функции-компонента.

```
function Time() {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(0)

    let currentTime = 0;

    const setCurrentTime = () => {
      currentTime = time;
    }
    // ...
    return <> </
}
```

Если currentTime в области видимости функции, она уничтожается и создаётся новая.

Решение, хранить состояние вне скоупа функции(во внешней переменной, в сервисе, в redux store, в другом useState, где угодно снаружи):

```
let currentTime = 0;
function Time() {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(0)
    const setCurrentTime = () => {
      currentTime = time;
    }
    // ...
    return <> </
}
```